# Wordpress filter - replace "src" with "load-src"

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm fighting with simple Wordpress lazy load plugin.

I need to change `"src"` attribute with `"load-src"`, so then I'll be able to use `jQuery` to load images when I need them. I know that I should use filters.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'filter');
function filter($content) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/(<\s*img[^>]+)(src\s*=\s*"[^"]+")([^>]+>)/i', 'noidea', $content);
}
```

Could you help me with the regex, I don't really understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the regex, just use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/function.str-replace.php).

```
add_filter('the_content', 'filter');
function filter($content) {
    return str_replace('src="', 'load-src="', $content);
}
```